# Writing a bootloader: understanding paritioning

Tags: x86, bootloader, bios

I am trying to write a bootloader for x86 architecture. I am following a course on the internet to learn how to do it.

There is something that I don't understand: how a partition is loaded.

In the partition table there are 4 entries, how does the MBR know which one he has to load?

Also, in the course, the instructor is writing a Bios Parameter Block (BPB) for I guess what will be a FAT partition. I've read in many sources on the internet that there is one BPB for each partition, and that BPB is supposed to be located at the start of the partition.
However, the instructor is writing a BPB at the very start of the code.

Here is the code:

```
ORG 0x7c00
BITS 16

_start:
    jmp short start
    nop

times 33 db 0

start:
   jmp 0:step2

step2:
    cli ; Clear Interrupts
    mov ax, 0x00
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00
    sti ; Enables Interrupts

jmp $

times 510-($ - $$) db 0

dw 0xAA55
```

From my understanding:

- at the _start label, the code defines an empty BPB
- at the start label, the code sets the code segment and the program counter
- at step2, the code sets all of the other segments and the stack pointer
- after that, an unfinite loop
- at the end of the file, we fill the MBR up to the 510th byte
- we then write the bootloader signature

What I don't understand:

- this code will be loaded at address 0x7C00 and execution will start from this address. However at this address there is no code but a BPB which is a data structure.
- there is no partition table, but there is still a BPB
- the BPB is located at the start of the code instead of at the start of a partition

Why so ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should note that `jmp short start` appears before the BPB in a Volume Boot Record (VBR) so when this volume boot sector is loaded into memory the first instruction jumps over the BPB data structure. Media can be partitioned or not partitioned. Floppy media is generally not partitioned and has a single VBR (first sector of the disk) and no MBR (Master Boot Record). Partitioned media (like hard drives) have a Master Boot Record which contains a Partition Table. Each Volume has a VBR.

Comment: If you are on partitioned media the 1st sector of the drive has an MBR that contains a partition table. The BIOS will load this sector into memory at physical address 0x7c00 and jump to it. An MBR usually doesn't have a BPB, but has a partition table with 4 entries. Each entry are 16 bytes. The first byte of each entry is whether it is active or not. A value of 0x80 means it is active, a value of 0x00 is inactive. A disk manager will set the partition active that a user requested (ie: with fdisk or other such tool). Only one partition should be marked active!

Comment: ... (partitioned media continued)... The job of a traditional  MBR (after loaded and started to run in memory at 0x7c00) is to relocate itself in memory (copy itself) (often at physical address 0x00600), start executing its code at the new location then it searches its own partition table for the active partition, then use the information to load the Volume Boot Record of the active partition into memory at 0x07c00 ontop of where the MBR used to be. Then the MBR code jumps to the VBR code at physical address 0x7c00 and the VBR starts executing (this process is called chain loading)

Comment: ... (partitioned media continued)... A VBR for DOS may contain a BPB etc. The job of the VBR is to start the process of loading the operating system into memory from the partition in which it resides.

Comment: On unpartitioned media there is no MBR. There is a sole VBR (with a BPB) that starts loading the operating system into memory. In essence with unpartitioned media spans the drive.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you very much for these clear explanations on a quite complex topic.

Comment: @MichaelPetch "An MBR usually doesn't have a BPB" so it seems that I can remove the BPB definition from my code, right ?

Comment: If you are creating partitioned media your MBR should have a partition table and not a BPB. If you are using real hardware USB drives (thumb drives etc) often can be booted at USB-FDD (Floppy emulation) or USB-HDD (Hard drive emulation). If booting as FDD emulation ensure your media is unpartitioned and that you have a BPB and no partition table. If you use HDD emulation you should not need a BPB but make sure your media is partitioned and the MBR has a partition table with exactly one partition marked bootable (active).